# JavaScript обратиться к экземпляру "родительской" функции

Tags: javascript

Можно ли из экземпляра функции обратиться к экземпляру "родительской" функции, внутри которого был создан данный экземпляр. Например в функции `get_parent_a_key` получить `a.a_key`?

```js
function A() {
  this.a_key = 0;
  this.b = new B;
}

function B() {
  this.b_key = 0;
  this.get_parent_a_key = function() {
    // HOW?
  }
}

a = new A;
result = a.b.get_parent_a_key();
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А передать ссылку на родителя в конструктор потомку не подойдет?

```js
function A() {
  this.a_key = 0;
  this.b = new B(this);
}

function B(parent) {  
  this.b_key = 0;
  this.get_parent_a_key = () => parent.a_key;
}

const a = new A;
console.log(a.b.get_parent_a_key());
```